# Hstore+Rails Access all the possible fields in a hstore column

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, postgresql, hstore

*Note: The formulation of this question tries to model a chronological evolution of an app. So each context is an evolution of the former one, aka following iteration with added fields/functionalities*

**===   Context in TIME 0**

1. I've got an application with `User` model. This model has an **hstore** column called `info`
2. The column `info` intends to store keys `['name', 'first_surname', 'phone']`. Also`store_accessor :name, :first_surname, :phone` is used.
3. Several users are created, filling those three fields. Let's say we have 10 of these users.
4. When I want to display the profile of the user, I do it this way:

*(This renders each field of the user table in a table, including all fields within the `info` hstore column.)*

```rb
Reference:"PROFILE SHOW"

#app/views/users/profile.html.erb
<h3>Profile</h3>

  <table class="table table-striped">
    <tbody>
      <tr><th>Email</th><th><%=current_user.email%></th></tr>
      <% unless current_user.info.nil? %>
        <% current_user.info.each do |key,val| %>
          <tr>
            <th><%=key.gsub('_',' ').titleize%></th>
            <th><%=val%></th>
          </tr>
        <% end %>
      <% end %>
    </tbody>
  </table>
```

**===   Context in TIME 1**

1. Now I decided that for each user I want to store also `city`, `province`, `passport`.
2. I am going to store those new fields as key/value pairs within the `info` column of `User`.
3. Whenever there is a new Signup, the sign-up form presents those three fields(`city,province,passport`), so the user can fill them in.
4. When I want to render the profile of a recently created user the code used in Ref."PROFILE SHOW"(see above) works well.

**Question**: How can I modify the code "PROFILE SHOW" so that it works also with the first 10 created `User`, during context **TIME 0**. In such a way that the page would render

```
|province |     |
|city     |     |
|passport |     |
```

I.e. blank space at those fields that did not exist in `info` during context **TIME 0**.

In other words: how does one keep track of "potential" fields in a `hstore` column, that is fields that exist in other instances but not in yours.

This is **desirable because** I would like to present them in the EDIT page too, so the user can fill the fields that did not exist before.

My approaches so far:

- Keep all the fields in an array, and instantiate it in the controller method, and then change the "PROFILE SHOW" code:

```rb
#app/controllers/users_controller.rb
def profile
  @info_attributes=%w(name first_surname phone passport city province)
end

#app/views/profile.html.erb
<% @info_attributes.each do |key| %>
 ...
<% end %>
```

- Do the same but keep that attribute array inside some kind of global variable/cache, which is read inside the controller method, and assigned to the instance variable.

thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> how does one keep track of "potential" fields in a hstore column, that is fields that exist in other instances but not in yours

There's no direct way, because a `hstore` is just a key/value store as a field value. It has no relationship to any other `hstore` value.

If you wish to define a list of known keys, your application must maintain that its self with a side table of possible keys, either as individual rows or as a single `hstore` field with each key pointing to a dummy placeholder value. I recommend individual rows for better concurrency.

Comment: I was afraid that was the case :( any thoughts on the approaches I suggested?

Comment: My Rails-fu is extremely lacking bordering on non-existent. I'd model it *in the database* as a separate relation used as a lookup table for candidate keys. If I was implementing this in a familar language, I'd probably read that candidate key table into memory during startup and cache it as an in-memory array to present in the user interface. I'd also add an option to disable/hide a candidate key so it wasn't listed anymore, and probably add `listen/notify` based alerts to long-running processes knew to update their caches when the key list changed.

Comment: thanks for the suggestion. Since it's a matter of <10 fields I will keep it as a `UserInfo` table, whose rows will be indeed cached.